# Replace null values in JSON

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I'm using a compare table and some values in my datasets doesn't exists. So when I'm trying to calculate the percentage between two rows I got no values. For example I got this image :

[image: compare table]

In the forst line I got Null and 186. So I would like to replace the Null to a 0 and get something like : `(0-186)/186` and get -100%. So I would like to know if it's possible to replace the value in JSON because with SAQL it would prevent me to dynamically sort my table.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may work

IFNULL([Text],'0')

Comment: unless you further expand on your answer, this is better suited as a comment

Answer (score -1):

Try making use of coalesce (field name,0) it will any NULL value for the field with 0.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to do it in JSON, I don't know if it will works.